# Packing distinguishable objects into boxes

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many ways are there to pack $18$ different books into $6$ boxes with $3$ books each
if

(a) all $6$ boxes are sent to different addresses?

(b) all $6$ boxes are sent to the same address?

(c) $3$ of the boxes are shipped to three different addresses while $3$ are left to be addressed
later?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_coefficient#Ways_to_put_objects_into_boxes

Answer (score 2):

(a) $\frac{18!}{(3!)^6}$.

The number of ways to line the books up in a row of 18 is $18!$. Suppose we do that, then put the first 3 in the box going to location A, the second 3 in that going to location B, etc. Then we've overcounted, because we could have rearranged the first three books, going to location A, in $3! = 6$ different ways, and the same for the B box, the C box, and the other three boxes. That means $18!$ is too high by a factor of $(3!)^6$.

(b) $\frac{1}{6!}\frac{18!}{(3!)^6}$.

If the boxes are all going to the same place, then it doesn't matter which box was the A box, the B box, etc., either. So the answer to (a) is still overcounting by a factor of the number of ways to rearrange the six boxes, $6!$.

(c) $\frac{1}{3!}\frac{18!}{(3!)^6}$.

I think (c) might be somewhat open to interpretation, because I'm not clear about what addressing the other boxes later entails.